# cant link header file to xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

[image]

I am sure this may be super silly but I have been spending so many hours trying to figure this out and looking everywhere. I added a 3rd party library to my Xcode project and when compiling it says that the header is missing even though I dragged the entire library to my projects.

Is there a way to manually link the header to my project? What am I missing? thanks!!

Not sure if this helps. I am trying to add ShopSavvy scanner. In Finder, I have a library called ScannerKit where my .xcodeproj is. Under the ScannerKit library there is a Headers library where all the headers are.

Comment: are you including the library's .h file in your code where you are calling into the library?  Can you include a screenshot of the compile errors you're seeing in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you checked copy when you added it in?
Try deleting it, then importing it again, making sure the box is checked.

Sometimes a library may have the header outside of the main library, for example I know TestFlightApp do this, `TestFlightApp.h` is outside the main library.

What library are you trying to use?

Comment: Have you checked any dependancies for the new Library?, It might need you to include a standard library for your project.Edit: Sorry just seen your screenshot, its not a dependancies issue.

Comment: There is a demo project right? Are they importing "ScannerKit.h" or something else? Sometimes it might be `import "ScannerKit/ScannerKit.h"`

Answer (score 0):

This has often happened to me, and I have found that sometimes it depends *where* in your project the header is located. If you have a supporting files folder, I would put it there. Really anywhere inside the classes folder. I'm not really sure why this problem occurs, though.